# Xamarin.Android HttpClient PostAsync gets cancelled when in Release

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, dotnet-httpclient, system.net.webexception

My application utilizes a few REST API endopints using HttpClient. My GetAsyncs are working perfectly fine both when used in Debug and Release mode.

The problem occurs when I try to PostAsync a large picture to the API in Release mode. The PostAsync gets cancelled and a WebException is raised (with the message: "A task was cancelled"). I do not cancel the task anywhere in my code. Increasing the timeout doesn't work either - the error occurs approximately 20 seconds after PostAsync gets fired.

In Debug mode the PostAsync works fine and uploads a picture in a few seconds when proper connection quality exists. To get it working in Release I need to check the Shared Runtime usage option in configuration.

What might be the cause of such behavior? I don't want to use Shared Runtime in my application as I need to release it in Play Store.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried OkHttp HttpClient for dotnet? Xamarin's HttpClient is broken, it doesn't even consider timeout even after set.

Answer (score 0):

If you look under the solution explorer on the left, you can right click on References and select Edit References select .Net Assemblies and pick the dll to add to the project. When it is added the first time it will be in the references for future projects.

I went through and added my normal dlls even if not needed in the current project to get them in the reference list. Add every dll corresponding to httpclient  My app was working fine in debug mode but didn't work when released, after this it worked fine.